# Rules for editing questions

Tags: discussion, specific-question, editing

This question recently was edited and approved: [How to protect a space elevator against terrorism](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20311/how-to-protect-a-space-elevator-against-terrorism)

The edit provided an embedded picture and link to a relevant xkcd comic. The comic was already linked in a comment. While it is related topically, and might add a little humor to the original question, I fail to see how this edit improves the question in a meaningful way. In addition, the comic contains a certain four-letter word that would otherwise probably be edited away.

What are some rules or guidelines to consider when editing/reviewing edits for other members' posts? While these could be subjective, my first thought is that an edit should:

1. Not violate the original intent of the question
2. Provide meaningful improvements to the overall quality of the post.

Any thoughts about this question in particular? About general editing guidelines?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think I'd ever approve an edit that added an image. I prefer links, as they don't clutter up the post as much, and provide a more professional look. But I guess it comes down to personal preference.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh, you actualy did: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/9409

Comment: I have for my part to admit that I skipped it. I was a bit unsure, and after all, I haven't been here that long. I was curious what was the take of the community, so thanks for raising the question.

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin Oh, *that's* what that was! I got confused by the syntax, I guess. There was no image in the preview.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh, no there wasn't. I only realised reading the link... XKCD could *only* be an image... :-)

Comment: @bilbo_pingouin It could also be a link to an image... which is what I thought it was. Either way, I'm glad I've realized the error of my ways.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh. Those previews can be seen in both "rendered output" view and in "markdown" view. It's probably a good idea to check both. The `[![` at the beginning of the link indicates an image.

Answer (score 5):

The edit in question, had I reviewed it, would have got a reject vote. It violates the intent of the original author. More to the point, it doesn't add any pertinent, *permanent* detail. The XKCD comic link is nice to have - but in a comment, an ephemeral bit of text that can be quickly deleted if needed. It's not appropriate in the question.

I've rolled the edit back.

Answer (score 4):

As can be seen in the comments, it turns out I accepted the edit by mistake, not realizing that the new syntax would display an image. I definitely agree with the rollback, and apologize for my mistake.

I guess the lesson to be learned is that it's a good idea to thoroughly review edits, especially those containing code you do not understand. I will certainly be more diligent in the future.

Comment: I made the same mistake. I apologize!